# SMTP cannot connect in LabVIEW

Tags: smtp, labview

i want to send an email from labview with an attachment. i check telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 and this port is open and my computer has an access to it. but i don't know whats the problem is LabVIEW.
and also ,i have tried smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465 but the problem is still. the connection everything is ok.

Thanks for helping me.
Best Regards

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add a colon between server name "smtp.gmail.com" and port "587"

https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvcomm/smtp_open_handle.html

> **server address** specifies the hostname or IP address of the SMTP server
> you want to use to send emails. **You also can specify a port number by
> appending a colon and the port number** to the hostname or IP address in
> the format hostname:port. By default, LabVIEW uses port 25, which
> works only for non-TLS SMTP servers.

Comment: thank you, i changed gmail to yahoo with this config : smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465 but now i get this error :
LabVIEW: An error occurred while receiving data from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Finally done!

i send by outlook service.